# is it possible for me to click the button several times to change the text that shows?

Tags: javascript, html

im actually new to scripting and i am planning to do my own blog site (with my own touch) but it seems i've stumbled upon a roadblock..

the thing is, i wanted a button that changes the text that shows up on screen, and i have successfully did that by using a code that i borrowed from w3schools lol..

here is the code that i used: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_text

it swapped the text by clicking on a button.. now the question is, would i be able to change the swapped text with another text just by clicking on the same button again? cuz that's what i am initially going for.

Comment: try it and see what happens. It's important to try to solve problems on your own before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use else if statement continuously

```
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Hello") {
   x.innerHTML = "Swapped text!";
  } else if (x.innerHTML === "Swapped text"){
   x.innerHTML = "Some another text...";
  } else if (x.innerHTML === "Some another text..."){
   x.innerHTML = "Again some text";
}
}
```

Like this you have to continue, if you have multiple texts

I hope you understood and am a beginner in these.
Thank You